# ASP.NET authentication timeout and Logout Events

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication

From my understanding after Googling the issue, the authentication ticket used by ASP.NET for user authentication expires after a set amount of time at which point any postback or page loads will cause the user to be redirected to a login page. However, there is no event that gets triggered when the ticket times out. Therefore, if I wish to implement a logout event, it won't get triggered when the ticket expires.

My question is: Is there anyway to circumvent this issue? I need to log when users log out of my website but if the ticket times out and the user gets redirected to the login page and thinks that they've been logged out so they just close the browser, I will never have a record of when they log out.

Thanks

Comment: There is no guaranteed way to know if the user has been logged out, since there are many things that can happen that would interfere.  For instance, if the worker process was reset or recycled.  Since "login" is not an actual event and is not tracked in asp.net, neither is logout.  The best you can do is timeout, either in Application_EndSession or something else.  You should also know that closing the browser does not "log out", since the authentication cookie is still valid.  The user could re-open the browser and navigate to the page again and still be "logged in".

Comment: My advice is to forget about this "feature", because it's impossible to make sure it's accurate.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I was afraid of. I guess I will have to come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this kind of behavior done by putting the custom object to asp.net cache. You set the cache timeout to the same time-frame as session and you refresh it every time user comes to the website. When cache timeout method is fired you know that user session ended.

This is dirty approach though, application can be restarted, user can return, session is ended, but it does not mean that user is logged out.